# command output to the specified tab PyQt

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I am using PyQt5 Python and I can't seem to specify the
console output tab, my current code duplicates the output on both tabs in the textedit, this however is the closest I've been to achieving what I want. I tried using pushButton.isEnabled() but it doesn't seem to work well with my setup, I also tried a conditional statement at the **name** section but couldnt reference the pushbutton action. If you have any advice on how to move forward please let me know. Just to be clear I am trying to get Budget output in the Budget Tab and actuals in the actuals tab currently it is printing on both tabs.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'DB.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QAction, QLineEdit, QMessageBox
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
import subprocess
import os
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)

class MyStream(QtCore.QObject):
    message = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyStream, self).__init__(parent)

    def write(self, message):
        self.message.emit(str(message))

    #def flush(self):
    #    sys.stdout.flush()


class Ui_Dialog(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def  __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_Dialog, self).__init__(parent)

        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(Dialog)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 401, 301))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 30, 171, 22))
        self.comboBox.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.comboBox.setEditable(True)
        self.comboBox.setCurrentText("Select Fiscal Year")
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("FY14 Budget")
        self.comboBox.addItem("FY15 Budget")
        self.comboBox.addItem("FY16 Budget")
        self.comboBox.addItem("FY17 Budget")
        self.comboBox.addItem("FY18 Budget")
        self.comboBox.addItem("FY19 Budget")
        self.comboBox.addItem("FY19 Budget Upadated")
        self.comboBox.addItem("FY20 Budget")
        self.comboBox.addItem("FY21 Budget")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 230, 161, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Budget) 

        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 100, 391, 111))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")


        #self.textEdit.setText(subprocess.check_output((self.Budget)))

        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 230, 161, 31))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")

        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_2)
        self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 10, 161, 22))
        self.comboBox_2.setEditable(True)
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("July")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("August")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("September")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("October")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("November")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("December")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("January")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("February")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("March")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("April")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("May")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("June")

        self.comboBox_3 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_2)
        self.comboBox_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 40, 161, 22))
        self.comboBox_3.setEditable(True)
        self.comboBox_3.setObjectName("comboBox_3")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("2014")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("2015")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("2016")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("2017")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("2018")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("2019")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("2020")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("2021")

        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 100, 391, 111))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 230, 161, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.Actuals) 

        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 230, 161, 31))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.comboBox.setCurrentIndex(-1)
        self.comboBox_2.setCurrentIndex(-1)
        self.comboBox_3.setCurrentIndex(-1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)


    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.comboBox.setCurrentText(_translate("Dialog", "Select Fiscal Year"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Run"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Cancel"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("Dialog", "Budget Export"))
        self.comboBox_2.setCurrentText(_translate("Dialog", "Select Month"))
        self.comboBox_3.setCurrentText(_translate("Dialog", "Select Year"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Run"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Cancel"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("Dialog", "Actuals Import"))

    def Actuals(self):
        print("Actuals")

        Monthvalue = self.comboBox_2.currentText() 
        Yearvalue= self.comboBox_3.currentText() 

        Monthdict={
            "July" :"07",
            "August" :"08",
            "September" :"09",
            "October" :"10",
            "November" :"11",
            "December" :"12",
            "January" :"01",
            "February" : "02",
            "March" : "03",
            "April" : "04",
            "May" : "05",
            "June" : "06"}

        #print("Button2: ",pushButton_2)
        concted=str(Monthdict[Monthvalue]) +" & "+ str(Yearvalue)
        print("Actuals: ",concted)

        #cmd=subprocess.Popen([r'newHello.exe',concted],stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,shell=True)
        """
        cmd = [r'BudgetExport.exe',concted]
        #cmd = [r'BudgetExport.py']    
        #stdout, stderr = cmd.communicate()

        output = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        output.wait(1000)
        #subprocess.check_call('true',shell=True)
        comms=output.communicate()
        print("=====================================")
        msg=comms[0].decode("utf-8")

        print("Output_Type: ",type(msg))
        msg_splt=[]
        msg_splt=msg.split("\r\n")

        print("=====================================")
        #print (comms)
        num=0
        for x in msg_splt:
            num+=1
            print(num,": ",x)

        print("=====================================")
        #print (comms)
        """

    def Budget(self):
        value = self.comboBox.currentText() 

        Datedict={
          "FY14 Budget" :"07/2013",
          "FY15 Budget" :"07/2014",
          "FY16 Budget" :"07/2015",
          "FY17 Budget" :"07/2016",
          "FY18 Budget" :"07/2017",
          "FY19 Budget" :"07/2018",
          "FY19 Budget Upadated" :"07/2018",
          "FY20 Budget" : "07/2019",
          "FY21 Budget" : "07/2020"}

        concted=str(value) +" & "+ str(Datedict[value])
        #cmd=subprocess.Popen([r'newHello.exe',concted],stdout

        cmd = [r'BudgetExport.exe',concted]
        #cmd = [r'BudgetExport.py']    
         #stdout, stderr = cmd.communicate()

        output = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        output.wait(1000)
        #subprocess.check_call('true',shell=True)
        comms=output.communicate()
        print("=====================================")
        msg=comms[0].decode("utf-8")

        print("Output_Type: ",type(msg))
        msg_splt=[]
        msg_splt=msg.split("\r\n")

        print("=====================================")
    #print (comms)
        num=0
        for x in msg_splt:
           num+=1
           print(num,": ",x)

        print("=====================================")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def Budget_myStream_message(self, message):
         self.textEdit.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
         self.textEdit.insertPlainText(message)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def Actual_myStream_message(self, message):
         self.textEdit_2.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
         self.textEdit_2.insertPlainText(message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()

    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.__init__(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    myStream = MyStream()

    myStream.message.connect(ui.Budget_myStream_message)  
    myStream.message.connect(ui.Actual_myStream_message)



    sys.stdout = myStream
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You want to choose in which text edit (`textEdit` or `textEdit_2`) your `print()`ed text will go?

Comment: Exactly, right now it is printing to both textedit and textedit_2, this line {myStream.message.connect(ui.Budget_myStream_message)  
    myStream.message.connect(ui.Actual_myStream_message)
} is what's throwing me off, I split them up because before it was only printing to the first textedit and leaving the second blank but now they are just replicating in both tabs

Comment: I would connect a single function, but inside that function you choose which `textEdit` writes the message if the message starts with a specific symbol (which you then strip). For example `print("£1" + "Hi there!")` goes to the first tab and `print("£2" + "General Kenobi")` goes to the second. You also want a third case where, if the specific symbol is not found (prints for code other than yours, errors, etc.) you write the message in one of the tabs by default, or both tabs, what you prefer.

Comment: Another idea would be to connect/disconnect the right/wrong textEdit at the beginning of each function. That way you don't have to modify the printed text.

Answer (score 0):

I think connect/disconnecting the writing function on the fly would work.

Your code is quite long so here is only the parts that I modified:

```
class Ui_Dialog(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def  __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        ...
        sys.stdout = MyStream()
        sys.stdout.message.connect(self.Budget_myStream_message)
        sys.stdout.message.connect(self.Actual_myStream_message)
        ...

    def Actuals(self):
        sys.stdout.message.disconnect(self.Budget_myStream_message)
        sys.stdout.message.connect(self.Actual_myStream_message)
        ...
        print("Actuals")
        ...

    def Budget(self):
        sys.stdout.message.connect(self.Budget_myStream_message)
        sys.stdout.message.disconnect(self.Actual_myStream_message)
        ...
        print("Budget")
        ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()

    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.__init__(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    # Delete that:
    #myStream = MyStream()
    #myStream.message.connect(ui.Budget_myStream_message)  
    #myStream.message.connect(ui.Actual_myStream_message)
    sys.stdout = myStream
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Just an update: I couldn't get it to run using the disconnect at the start of the functions Actual & Budget  so I deleted the disconnect from the beginning and it worked

Comment: Ah that's strange. Without the `disconnect`s I would expect the message to go in both consoles again after using each function once. The error you get is when you try to disconnect something already disconnected, I'm sure you can figure a proper `try-except` to ignore that.

Comment: That's what I thought, it must be because the connection is being made at the click of a button so I might be better off disconnecting at end of each function